# Archive project in Swift 3 and get "command failed due to signal segmentation fault 11"

Tags: swift3, archive

I updated my code for Swift 3, run on devices and everything works, but when I Archive project, after cleaning and deleting Delivered Data, I have error "command failed due to signal segmentation fault 11"

**My logs**

0  swift                    0x000000010a5ffb6d PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45

1  swift                    0x000000010a5ff5b6 SignalHandler(int) + 470

2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff9560152a _sigtramp + 26

3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff5825ab50 _sigtramp + 3267728960

4  swift                    0x0000000107d29432 swift::CastOptimizer::optimizeUnconditionalCheckedCastAddrInst(swift::UnconditionalCheckedCastAddrInst*) + 1554

5  swift                    0x0000000107db144d processFunction(swift::SILFunction&, bool, unsigned int) + 1901

6  swift                    0x0000000107db7f9f (anonymous namespace)::ConstantPropagation::run() + 47

7  swift                    0x0000000107d4862d swift::SILPassManager::runOneIteration() + 6077

8  swift                    0x0000000107d4d7d6 swift::runSILOptimizationPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 3462

9  swift                    0x0000000107a153cb performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 20107

10 swift                    0x0000000107a0e265 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 17029

11 swift                    0x00000001079cb82d main + 8685

12 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff8936c5ad start + 1

13 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000006d start + 1992899265
Stack dump:

***and this***

1. While running pass #1059521 SILFunctionTransform "Constant Propagation" on SILFunction "@_TTSg5VSC29UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKeyS_s8Hashable5UIKit_P__CSo8NSObjectS2_S0_10ObjectiveC_Ps9AnyObject____TFs17_dictionaryUpCastu2_Rxs8Hashable0_S_rFGVs10Dictionaryxq__GS0_q0_q1__".

Can someone help or tell, where should I search bug?

Comment: I have the very same issue - will let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: This solved the problem for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26108868/3874596

Comment: @denjiz thanks, it resolved it for me too)

Comment: Thanks @denjiz, his answer helped me)
[answer for my issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26108868/3874596)

Comment: hmm. how can lowering optimization level help or even be marked as correct solution?

Comment: @DenRee could you check if my answer helped in your case? Thx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my case I was passing launchOptions as function parameter to another class inside

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`

After migrating to Swift 3, migrator added cast to match awaited parameter's type, which was of type `[NSObject : AnyObject]?` (pre Swift 3)

All I had to do is just update my custom function to take `[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]` as parameter and remove that false cast. Simple as that

I didn't have to compromise any optimization level (which shouldn't even be the last resort for developers, this is definitely not a way how to solve compiler errors/segmentation faults). After removing cast all is working fine with swift's whole module optimization.

Comment: ily! saved me some time for suure

Comment: It helped! In my case it was a reuse of code shipped by Amazon with their Mobile Hub solution. They don't update it very often, I guess, so be careful!

Comment: I had the same problem, your solution just saved me!  In my case it was the AWS mobile client demo code causing the issue, but only when I tried to archive.

Comment: Thanks guys, glad to hear it's working & saved time for you!