# Xcode 8.2.1/Swift 3.0 Product/Archive failing with Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, archive

I went to create a Archive through Xcode and was presented with

```
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11                              

            #selector(NSDecimalNumberBehaviors.scale)
0  swift                    0x00000001067b93ad PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45
1  swift                    0x00000001067b8b56 SignalHandler(int) + 790
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fffd13feb3a _sigtramp + 26
3  swift                    0x0000000106722d51 llvm::MCDwarfLineTableHeader::getFile(llvm::StringRef&, llvm::StringRef&, unsigned int) + 3169
4  swift                    0x0000000105ae7c38 llvm::DwarfDebug::endModule() + 1080
5  swift                    0x0000000105abe571 llvm::AsmPrinter::doFinalization(llvm::Module&) + 2481
6  swift                    0x00000001065edee5 llvm::FPPassManager::doFinalization(llvm::Module&) + 53
7  swift                    0x00000001065f789b llvm::legacy::PassManager::run(llvm::Module&) + 1803
8  swift                    0x000000010391420a performLLVM(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::DiagnosticEngine&, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, llvm::GlobalVariable*, llvm::Module*, llvm::TargetMachine*, llvm::StringRef) + 8234
9  swift                    0x0000000103910ccb ThreadEntryPoint(swift::irgen::IRGenerator*, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, int) + 171
10 swift                    0x0000000103910d53 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (*)(swift::irgen::IRGenerator*, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, int), swift::irgen::IRGenerator*, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, int> >(void*) + 99
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fffd1408aab _pthread_body + 180
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fffd14089f7 _pthread_body + 0
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fffd14081fd thread_start + 13
```

The project compiles and runs perfectly fine (Cmd+R)

I've tried:

- Clearing the derived data
- Rebooting
- Searching both Google and SO for any viable options which might match my circumstances.

I've had this before, but have always had some idea of "where" the problem lies, there doesn't seem to be any indication from the stack trace of where to begin to look

The project is (reasonably) large and contains a number of other libraries managed through Carthage, so not easy to post.

I have a "sneaking" suspicion that having opened the project (by mistake) in Xcode 8.3b1 "might" be part of the issue

By following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536835/swift-project-builds-and-runs-but-fails-to-archive/26108868#26108868) I can make it work, but this is not a long term solution I want to live with.

I know this is long shot and it seems to every question on this has a different cause, but I'd really like to know ANY suggestions that I might look into to solve this issue